# Redirect basic page to external url when visiting page

Tags: theming, 8, hooks

I'm attempting to provide a field to users to enable them to enter an external url. If they enter a url I would like that basic page to redirect to the url the user provided instead of actually opening the node. I've made some attempts by using a preprocess node hook in my custom .theme file as seen here:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables){
    $node = Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
    $type = $node->getType();
    if($type == 'page'){
        $redirect = $node->get('field_redirect')->value;
        if($redirect != ''){

            $response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($redirect);
            $response->send();
            Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->resetCache();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And I've also tried creating a module to do it and using an entity_view hook like so

```
<?php

function mymodule_entity_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  if ($entity->getEntityType()->id() == 'node' && $entity->bundle() == 'page' && !$entity->field_redirect->isEmpty()) {
    $value = $entity->field_redirect->getValue();
    $redirect = $value[0]['value'];
    $response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($redirect);
    $response->send();
    return;
  }
}
```

Each of these solutions work the first time, but don't work the 2nd time or any time after that until I clear the cache. I'm assuming this is a caching issue. I've heard that using cache tags could resolve this issue but I'm not sure how I would use them. Also I'm not married to making any of these solutions work I merely want to implement some way to perform redirects on pages, it doesn't matter to me how.

Is it possible to perform redirects on node pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a cache problem. You need to set correctly the cache tags and context for the entity and it will work.
You need to do something like this to skip the cache:

```
  '#cache' => ['max-age' => 0],
```

you can find more info here: https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/cache/tags

**Notes**:

- This needs to be put on `hook_entity_view_alter()` on the entity in your case the node, or if you want in just one field for which you want to set it. This is a work around for your redirect issue!
- Try to add it to the `$entity`, if it doesn't work you need to replace the default '#cache' or you can add it to the `$build` array, this is case dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the NodeViewController (and invoke it via an own NoteRouteProvider) in your module and return the redirect there instead of the $build array. Feels much cleaner to me.