# How to do a redirect in node.html.twig?

Tags: 8, redirection

I'm trying to do a redirect on my `node.html.twig` template based on the content type because I'm using views for my content.

I tried this:

```
{% do redirect('/example') %}
```

or this:

```
{% redirect '/example' %}
```

but nothing works. Any idea?

Comment: You shouldn't (and hopefully can't) perform a redirect in the template layer. This needs to be done much further up the chain

Comment: Did you try just having a Views path set to `node/%nid` to overtake content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do it in the Twig file. This is not where that logic belongs. It should be in an Event.

See this similar question: [EventSubscriber called on specific node type or path](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/240159/eventsubscriber-called-on-specific-node-type-or-path)

All that is left is checking the node type and sending a `RedirectResponse`.

Gabe Sullice has a Gist that sounds very close to what you are trying to accomplish: https://gist.github.com/gabesullice/96bdae1518d11bb4565e72c33ffcae4c

So your code would fill in something like:

```
  /**
   * Determines whether we should send a RedirectResponse for this node.
   */
  protected function redirectApplies(NodeInterface $node) : bool {
    $redirect_types = ['type_1', 'type_2', 'type_3'];
    return in_array($node->getType(), $redirect_types);
  }
```

But if you go to different urls for different types, you will need to adjust it a little more.

Comment: Yes, the logic belongs either in the controller or in an event subscriber. Instead of  the response event (as in the linked Gist) a faster option would be the request event, see this change record https://www.drupal.org/node/2013014.

Comment: This method works perfectly, i used and modified a few this code and works finally @kevin

Answer (score 0):

Where did you see the redirect functionality? I dont think it's part of standard twig or anything drupal provides: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates

You'd be better of doing the redirect in a proprocess function maybe. This might help 
[Redirect basic page to external url when visiting page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217049/redirect-basic-page-to-external-url-when-visiting-page)

Comment: It looks like its a function in CraftCMS but not in Twig itself. https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/redirect.html

Comment: (that is to say, they must have created a custom Twig function and it shows up in google results - it also appears in BranchCMS).

Answer (score 0):

As @Kevin suggested
i created a custom module based on Gabe Sullice code:
https://gist.github.com/gabesullice/96bdae1518d11bb4565e72c33ffcae4c

My final code redirect to custom url by content type:

```
    namespace Drupal\redirect_node_module\EventSubscriber;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableRedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
/**
 * Class ResponseSubscriber.
 *
 * @package Drupal\redirect_node_module
 */
class ResponseSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
  /**
   * Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch definition.
   *
   * @var Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch
   */
  protected $routeMatch;
  /**
   * Constructor.
   */
  public function __construct(CurrentRouteMatch $current_route_match) {
    $this->routeMatch = $current_route_match;
  }
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events['kernel.response'] = ['handle'];
    return $events;
  }
  /**
   * This method is called whenever the kernel.response event is
   * dispatched.
   *
   * @param GetResponseEvent $event
   */
  public function handle(Event $event) {
    $route_name = $this->routeMatch->getRouteName();
    switch ($route_name) {
      case 'entity.node.canonical':
        $node = $this->routeMatch->getParameter('node');
        if ($this->redirectApplies($node)) {
          $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->getRedirect($node)));
        }
    }
  }
  /**
   * Determines whether we should send a RedirectResponse for this node.
   */
   protected function redirectApplies(NodeInterface $node) {
    // One should have logic here returning TRUE or FALSE for whether we should redirect this response.
    $redirect_on = ['programas', 'servicios', 'aliados', 'testimonios', 'nosotros', 'nuestro_equipo', 'datos_de_contacto', 'banner', 'seccion'];
    return (in_array($node->getType(), $redirect_on));

  }
  protected function getRedirect(NodeInterface $node) {
    // We can cache this response when this is fixed: https://www.drupal.org/node/2573807
    // $response = CacheableRedirectResponse::create($url);
    // $response->addCacheableDependency($node);
    // return $response;

    switch ($node->getType()) {
      case 'nuestro_equipo':
        $url = "/profesionales";
        break;

      case 'datos_de_contacto':
        $url = "/contacto";
        break;

      case 'nosotros':
        $url = "/nosotros";
        break; 

      case 'banner':
        $url = "/";
        break;  

      case 'testimonios':
        $url = "/testimonios";
        break;

      case 'aliados':
        $url = "/aliados";
        break;

      default:
        $search_chars = array('á','é','í','ó','ú','ñ','Á','É','Í','Ó','Ú','Ñ',' ');
        $replace_chars= array('a','e','i','o','u','n','a','e','i','o','u','n','-');
        $node_title = str_replace($search_chars, $replace_chars, strtolower( $node->getTitle() ));
        $url = "/".$node->getType()."/".$node_title;
        break;
    }
    return $url;
  }
}
```